# Button value output in console.log with JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, console.log

I'm fairly new to HTML and JS.
I need the value of my HTML button to show in the console.log with JS. I dont want to use onclick="..." though.

This is part of my HTML file:

```
<button id="kaufknopf" value="4,50">4,50€</button>
```

This is my JS file:

```
function output() {
    console.log(price);
}

var price = document.getElementById("kaufknopf").value;
price.addEventListener("click", output, true);
```

Comment: Please show what attempts you have made, the way your question is asked, it seems like this is a homework assignment and you want the community to give you the answer. That is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You have to add event listener on the html element not on the value of that element.

```
var price = document.getElementById( "kaufknopf" );
price.addEventListener( "click", output, true );
```

**2)** After you click on the button you have to grab its value using `price.value`

```
function output() {
  console.log( price.value );
}
```

```js
function output() {
  console.log(price.value);
}

var price = document.getElementById("kaufknopf");
price.addEventListener("click", output, true);
```

```html
<button id="kaufknopf" value="4,50">4,50€</button>
```